# Data flow with Combine in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Hello  I had spend over 10 hour to implement `Combine` framework but can't clear understanding how to link `Publisher` and `Subscriber`. In example I just wanna call `setTheme` funk from `Theme` class and automatically update `game` variable in `Game` class. I know how to achieve it with `didSet` but main goal to make it with `Combine`. Would be thankfull for help.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

class Theme: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var choosenTheme: Color? // Publisher right?
    
    func setTheme(with color: Color?) {
        if let unwrappedColor = color {
            self.choosenTheme = unwrappedColor
        } else {
            self.choosenTheme = nil
        }
    }
}

class Game: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var game: String? // Subscriber right?
    private let gameTheme = Theme()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        addSubscribers()
    }
    
    private func addSubscribers() { // I think something wrong here
        gameTheme.$choosenTheme
            .map(createGame)
            .sink { [weak self] (returnedString) in
                print("Value from sink \(String(describing: returnedString))")
                self?.game = returnedString
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    private func createGame(for theme: Color?) -> String? {
       if let unwrappedTheme = theme {
           print(unwrappedTheme)
           return String("\(unwrappedTheme)")
       } else {
           return nil
       }
   }
}

// Test:
var testTheme = Theme()
testTheme.setTheme(with: .orange)

var testGame = Game()
print(testGame.game) // Should be Orange

testTheme.setTheme(with: .blue)
print(testGame.game) // Should be Blue

testTheme.setTheme(with: nil)
print(testGame.game) // Should be nil
```

Comment: That's not what Combine is for. Just make Theme a struct and SwiftUI will detect changes automatically.

Comment: @malhal as you can see Theme conforms to ObservableObject, I need this behavior and I tried to make example easy to reproduce without additional logic

Comment: Usually there is only one object in SwiftUI that holds the model structs in @Published properties

Comment: @malhal In case if I have different types of games and allow user to add own themes should I put everything in one ViewModel with a list of publishers? Would be thankful if you may be share some articles or project examples on git

Comment: Yes but the object that holds the model structs is usually called a store and not a view model. I recommend apple's wwdc videos to learn SwiftUI cause 3rd party articles usually have mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that there are two instances of `Theme`

one that you create here:

```
// Test:
var testTheme = Theme()
```

and another one inside `Game`:

```
private let gameTheme = Theme()
```

Then you are changing the first theme and expecting the second one to change. To fix the problem you have to inject the `Theme` into your `Game`.

First you need to make some changes to `Game` to allow of the `Theme` to be injected:

```
class Game: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var game: String?
    private let gameTheme: Theme
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(gameTheme: Theme) {
        self.gameTheme = gameTheme
        addSubscribers()
    }
```

Next you have to perform that injection when you test:

```
var testTheme = Theme()
testTheme.setTheme(with: .orange)

var testGame = Game(gameTheme: testTheme)
```

If you do that - you will see the changes correctly reflected in prints.

You could simplify your two classes significantly if you wished:

```
class Theme: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var chosenTheme: Color?
    
    func setTheme(with color: Color?) {
        chosenTheme = color
    }
}

class Game: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var game: String?
    private let gameTheme: Theme
    
    init(gameTheme: Theme) {
        self.gameTheme = gameTheme
        addBindings()
    }
    
    private func addBindings() {
        gameTheme
            .$chosenTheme
            .map(createGame)
            .assign(to: &$game)
    }
    
    private func createGame(for theme: Color?) -> String? {
        theme.map { $0.description }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't change at all. What you are doin is setting the theme of an instance of `Theme`. However, in your `Game` class you're listening to another one.

Do you see the problem now? either initialize your `Game` with the theme you're updating or make `Theme` a `singleton`.

Try this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

class Theme: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = Theme()
    @Published private(set) var choosenTheme: Color? // Publisher right?
    
    func setTheme(with color: Color?) {
        if let unwrappedColor = color {
            self.choosenTheme = unwrappedColor
        } else {
            self.choosenTheme = nil
        }
    }
}

class Game: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var game: String? // Subscriber right?
    private let gameTheme = Theme.shared
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        addSubscribers()
    }
    
    private func addSubscribers() { // I think something wrong here
        gameTheme.$choosenTheme
            .map(createGame)
            .sink { [weak self] (returnedString) in
                print("Value from sink \(String(describing: returnedString))")
                self?.game = returnedString
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    private func createGame(for theme: Color?) -> String? {
       if let unwrappedTheme = theme {
           print(unwrappedTheme)
           return String("\(unwrappedTheme)")
       } else {
           return nil
       }
   }
}

// Test:

var testGame = Game() //Game initialization should precede Theme because now the listener starts listening for the orange change 

var testTheme = Theme.shared
testTheme.setTheme(with: .orange)

print(testGame.game) // Should be Orange

testTheme.setTheme(with: .blue)
print(testGame.game) // Should be Blue

testTheme.setTheme(with: nil)
print(testGame.game) // Should be nil
```